# How does the log shipping technology (restore job) know exactly which file(s) to use for restore?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

At a high level, what concept is used by the log shipping restore job to use the correct file(s) during each restore operation (job execution)?

Answer (score 2):

Every backup in its `header` has 2 LSN that are sufficient to understand what was the log backup sequence:

**first_lsn**   numeric(25,0)   Log sequence number of the first or oldest log record in the backup set. Can be NULL.
**last_lsn**    numeric(25,0)   Log sequence number of the next log record after the backup set. Can be NULL.

link: [backupset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

You can find them by executing [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and I'll report you them from `msdb..backupset` so you can see how simple is is to find out the correct log backup sequence:

[image]

Every `LastLSN` as the description above says, reports the **next** log record after the backup set, so all you need is to find out the next the log backup to be restored is to find other log backup where the `FirstLSN` is that `LastLSN`.

Comment: So the log shipping restore job reads all the file headers to identify which file(s) to restore next?

Comment: I cannot prove this, it's only my thought. The only thing the job have when it needs to decide what file it needs to restore is the set of non-restored backup files and their headers should be read toin order to select the correct file

Answer (score 1):

**sepupic** provides a good answer to this question.  To know the LSN of the first log file to restore you can use the **redo_start_lsn** from [sys.master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The FirstLSN in the backup header should be less than or equal to the redo_start_lsn or the last_lsn from the previous log file restored.  The last_lsn should also be greater the redo_start_lsn or the last_lsn from the previous log file restored.

File dates can also be useful to determine the sequence of log files to restore to avoid checking the headers of all the log backups in the directory.   I think many log shipping implementations just rely on file dates but you can be sure by checking the header with `RESTORE HEADERONLY`.

I wrote my own log shipping tool as I needed something that could scale to thousands of databases.  I also had a requirement to be able to do log shipping directly from Azure blob for a different environment.  This tool is open source, so you are welcome to inspect the source code and see how it works under the hood.  https://github.com/trimble-oss/sql-log-shipping-service

**Edit - additional info:**

If you are using native log shipping there is a system stored procedure called [sys.sp_can_tlog_be_applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-can-tlog-be-applied-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  This does a `RESTORE HEADERONLY` to validate the redo_start_lsn from sys.master_files against the first_lsn & last_lsn from the header.  Here are a few snippets from the proc, but you can script it out from SSMS if you are interested.

```
    select @command = N'restore headeronly from disk = N''' + replace(@backup_file_name, N'''',N'''''') + N''''
    insert into @backup_header
        execute(@command)
```

```
    select @db_redo_start_lsn = min(redo_start_lsn)
    from master.sys.master_files
    where database_id = db_id (@database_name)
        and type = 0
        and state in (0,1)
        and redo_start_lsn is not null
```

```
    select top 1 @backupdbname = DatabaseName
                    ,@backup_first_lsn = ISNULL(FirstLsn, 0)
                    ,@backup_last_lsn = ISNULL(LastLsn, 0)
                    ,@backup_type = BackupType
    from @backup_header
```

```
    if (@db_redo_start_lsn >= @backup_first_lsn and @db_redo_start_lsn < @backup_last_lsn)
        select @result = 1
```

It appears that this is only used the first time the job runs.  When the process runs the next time it calls [sys.sp_help_log_shipping_secondary_database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-log-shipping-secondary-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which returns the name of the file last restored along with the date which I'm guessing is used to determine the next file to restore.  From this point on native log shipping doesn't appear to be checking the headers.

I identified this using an extended event session to capture the activity from native log shipping.

Comment: When I need to restore database to point in time I also do my script in base of the time of log backups, but the original question was about **log shipping** and the only reliable method in my opinion is based on LSN

Comment: I agree.  Checking the LSNs from the header is the only way to know for sure.  *My* log shipping tool checks the headers by default and also uses the file dates.  The header check can be disabled though.  If you restore the files out of sequence you will get a 4305 error if the file is too recent and a 4326 error if it's too old.  This won't break the restore operation.  I think checking the headers is still worthwhile though.